# Alert Dialog not showing when put in a class

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Here is my alert dialog class.

```
public class DialogCreator {

        public DialogCreator(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        private Context context;
        private int result = -1;
        public Type getResult() {
            switch(result) {
            case 0:
                return Type.QUEEN;
            case 1:
                return Type.KNIGHT;
            case 2:
                return Type.ROOK;
            case 3:
                return Type.BISHOP;
            }
            return null;
        }
        private Builder createDialog() {
            AlertDialog.Builder myPromotionDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
            myPromotionDialog.setTitle("Choose a piece to upgrade to...");
            String[] sortModeChoices = { "Queen", "Knight", "Rook", "Bishop"};
            myPromotionDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(sortModeChoices,
                    0, null);

            myPromotionDialog.setPositiveButton("Promote!",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            which = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView()
                                    .getCheckedItemPosition();
                            result = which;
                        }
                    });

            return myPromotionDialog;
        }
```

And here is how I'm running it:

```
DialogCreator whitePromotion = new DialogCreator(this);
                whitePromotion.createDialog().show();
                while (whitePromotion.getResult() == null) {}
                System.out.println(whitePromotion.getResult().toString());
```

The dialog is not showing up at all, my code is stuck at the while loop.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you get any error? then post your Logcat.

Comment: @geet I dont get any logcat it just says that my app is not responding. Which must mean its stuck in the while loop

Comment: private Builder createDialog()  since it is private, how can you access it?

Answer (score 0):

`while (whitePromotion.getResult() == null) {}` This is the loop you are in , Re check your logic

`result = -1;`

`switch` contains case for 0, 1, 2, 3

Dont try like this , this will run a endless loop in getResult() 

`Respond only when you got a`click

Comment: The reason I put that while loop is so further code does not get executed once the dialog is shown. Because when the dialog gets shown and the user selects a choice, `result` becomes either 0, 1, 2 or 3 and so the while loop breaks. This was my intention anyway...

Comment: what if the user doesnt respond more than a minute , your resource gets exausted .

Comment: You should create an interface to respond with your activity on click thats the proper way

Answer (score 0):

```
Your not showing it up at all please replace this

DialogCreator whitePromotion = new DialogCreator(this);
                whitePromotion.createDialog().show();
                while (whitePromotion.getResult() == null) {}
                System.out.println(whitePromotion.getResult().toString());

with this one

DialogCreator whitePromotion = new DialogCreator(this);
                AlertDialog alertDialog = whitePromotion.createDialog();
                alertDialog.show();
                while (whitePromotion.getResult() == null) {}
                System.out.println(whitePromotion.getResult().toString());
```